# Making maps responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently rendering a Joomla website responsive. But I'm having an issue with the SobiPro Map. I'm displaying a map (background img) and points (a link + img) over it with an absolute position, so if you reduce the size of the map it doesn't fit anymore.

[image]

Here is the html & css ->

```
<div id="system">
    <article class="item">
      <div class="content clearfix">
        <div id="plan-boutiques">
          <a href="#" id="repere-dia" style="" data-lightbox="width:600;type:iframe;">18</a>
          <!-- 31 links like this ^ -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#plan-boutiques {
  background: url(../images/rom/niveau.png) no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 374px;
  width: 685px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

And an id is applied to each points (31 in total) like this :

```
a#repere-dia {
  left: 391px;
  top: 182px;
}
```

I already tried to move pixel by pixel but with 30 points it's not the right solution so I'm looking for some jQuery or Javascript solutions.

**EDIT**

New problem : The background stay centered even if I reduce the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use percentage positioning instead of pixels in your css.

```
 a#repere-dia {
   left: 10.43%;
   top: 27.02%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
#plan-boutiques {
 background: url(../images/rom/niveau.png) no-repeat;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: No it doesn't work, if I change the height to auto the background is not displayed anymore. But I'm not looking on how to render the background responsive but the whole map with points over it